# Test if error occurred in a Guile function

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm trying to create a function in Guile which tests if an arbitrary expression threw an error or not, but have hit a wall.

```
(define (error-or-not qqx)
  (if
    (catch
      #t
      (lambda () ,qqx)
      (lambda (k . args) #t))
    #t
    #f))

(display (error-or-not `(/ 1 0))) ; => #t (1)
(newline)
(display (error-or-not `(/ 1 1))) ; => #t (2)
(newline)
```

`qqx` is a quasiquoted expression that is evaluated inside the `error-or-not` function and tested to see if it causes an error.

[The Guile manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Catch.html#Catch) in effect says that, if evaluating `qqx` throws an error, the `catch` function returns the value it gets from calling its third argument (the lambda which takes the arguments). This works fine if `qqx` actually does cause an error (see above #1).

But the manual also says that if there is no error, the `catch` function returns the value from evaluating `qqx`. This is not working out so well for me because I can't distinguish between the two cases (see above #2).

Can someone point out how to definitively tell when an error *did not* occur?

---

## Update

Chris Jester-Young has pointed out my mistake--see the accepted answer below. For completeness, I'm posting the version of his code I'm using (backported to Guile 1.8.8):

```
(use-syntax (ice-9 syncase))

(define (stub retval) (lambda args retval))

(define-syntax error-or-not
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr ...)
      (catch #t (lambda () expr ... #f) (stub #t)))))

(display (error-or-not (/ 1 0))) ; => #t
(newline)
(display (error-or-not (/ 1 1))) ; => #f
(newline)
```

Comment: Your code does not evaluate at all, since you have a free (unquote) form outside quasiquoting. Have you really included all your code?

Comment: @Dolda2000 - I've updated to a single code sample that will evaluate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As Chris Jester-Young pointed out in his answer, that still doesn't evaluate. The error message is `unquote: expression not valid outside of quasiquote in form (unquote qqx)`. Whatever are you doing to test that at all?

Comment: @Dolda2000 - thanks, I realise my error (pardon the pun) now. And to answer your question, I'm writing a unit-testing framework: GitHub:yawaramin/ggspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing quasiquoting; it doesn't do what you expect. In particular, it isn't a substitute for `eval`. The `(lambda () ,qqx)` you have creates a function that *always* fails when called, because `unquote` cannot be used outside of a `quasiquote` form.

The best way to implement the functionality you want is as a macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (error-or-not expr ...)
  (catch #t
         (lambda () expr ... #f)
         (const #t)))
```

Example:

```
(error-or-not (/ 1 0))   ; => #t
(error-or-not (/ 1 1))   ; => #f
```

---

Guile 1.8-compatible version:

```
(use-syntax (ice-9 syncase))
(define-syntax error-or-not
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr ...)
     (catch #t (lambda () expr ... #f)
               (lambda _ #t)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's clever. (Too bad about `unquote` though.) I'll update my question with your code, backported to Guile 1.8.

Comment: I'll add a Guile 1.8-compatible version, though, the Guile team no longer supports 1.x versions, in case you didn't already know. :-)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, thanks, but I'm targeting 1.8 because it's distributed with older versions of GnuCash.